# How to make a SQL query for get sum of data field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables as 1st one is  " stock " and 2nd one is " parts "

stock table data fields are

```
id | part_id | qty | status
```

parts table data fields are

```
id | partName | status
```

I coded for find sum of the qty field in the same part id.

That query as follows.

```
SELECT `stock`.`idstock`, `parts`.`partName`, SUM(`stock`.`qty`)
FROM `stock` INNER JOIN
     `parts` 
     ON `parts`.`id` = `stock`.`part_id`
WHERE `stock`.`statu`='1'
```

But this query is not running correctly.

I need to show sum of the qty data field for same part id as a list.

Comment: Let's rule out a typo - Is this right? `statu`='1'`

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you're trying to get the sum of quantities by part.
If so, it makes no sense to have `stock.idstock` in the select list, and you'll need a `group by` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT parts.id, parts.partName, sum(stock.qty)
FROM stock
INNER JOIN parts on stock.part_id = parts.id
WHERE stock.status = '1'
GROUP BY parts.id, parts.partName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that query working perfectly. Thank you again.....

Comment: In this stock table, status "1" is items in and status "2" is item out. I need to find stock available qty. and show it on a web page. Please help me to do it.